# SQL select image, aggregate functions with subqueries

Tags: sql, image, subquery, aggregate

I'm trying to write a query like the below. The table hnh contains a list of set products each with productimage, rangecode(type), itemnumber, price, description etc. SALESORDERHISTORY is a list of individual sales lines over the last year with columns for account, itemnumber, rangecode, salesqty and confirmeddate.

Aggregate functions are required in the query to select the last 3 months sales for each product line per selected customer, same for 12 months sales. This could change or average sales quantity.

```
select hnh.image, 
    hnh.rangecode, 
    hnh.itemnumber, 
    hnh.producttype, 
    hnh.productdescription, 
    hnh.price, 
    count(distinct a.SalesQty) as '3MonthSales', 
    count(distinct b.SalesQty) as '12MonthSales', 
    hnh.CurrentStock
    from HNHPRODUCTS hnh
inner join (select SALESQTY, itemid, configid, account from SALESORDERHISTORY 
    where confirmeddate > DATEADD(month, -3, getdate())) a on a.rangecode = hnh.rangecode and a.itemnumber = hnh.itemnumber and a.account = '1234'
inner join (select SALESQTY, itemid, configid, account from SALESORDERHISTORY 
    where confirmeddate > DATEADD(month, -12, getdate())) b on b.rangecode = hnh.rangecode and b.itemnumber = hnh.itemnumber and b.account = '1234'
```

I've seen quite a few examples but all with only one subquery, one aggregate function and no images. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me quite a while but the answer seems to be to create a subquery after 'from' for all items other than the image, then join back via primary key to select the image column:

```
select hnh.image as image, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, 3MonthSales....
from (select 
    hnh.ID as 't_id',
    hnh.rangecode as 'F1', 
    hnh.itemnumber as 'F2', 
    hnh.producttype as 'F3', 
    hnh.productdescription 'F4', 
    hnh.price as 'F5', 
    count(distinct a.SalesQty) as '3MonthSales', 
    count(distinct b.SalesQty) as '12MonthSales',
    ... 
    from HNHPRODUCTS hnh
    group by hnh.ID,
    hnh.rangecode, 
    hnh.itemnumber, 
    hnh.producttype, 
    hnh.productdescription, 
    hnh.price ...
join (select SALESQTY, itemid, configid, account from SALESORDERHISTORY 
    where confirmeddate > DATEADD(month, -3, getdate())) a on a.rangecode = hnh.rangecode and a.itemnumber = hnh.itemnumber and a.account = '1234'
join (select SALESQTY, itemid, configid, account from SALESORDERHISTORY 
    where confirmeddate > DATEADD(month, -12, getdate())) b on b.rangecode = hnh.rangecode and b.itemnumber = hnh.itemnumber and b.account = '1234') as x
left join x on HNHPRODUCTS.ID = x.t_id
```

If someone has a better solution by all means please update